# How can I retrieve the previous item of an ordered key/pair collection?

Tags: python, python-2.7

One of the most frustrating things about learning a new language is, well that you don't know how to do anything. I want to perform, what should be a simple task, but I am struggling to implement it.

I want to keep track of items that I have already traversed, along with their location.
I ant to be able to look back into the collection when I find an item, see if it's already been seen, and if so, what was it's location (line number). I then want to look at the last item found before the current one and review it's name and location.

I am parsing some unstructured text, and sometimes I match on unintended parts of word sections.

Take the following:

```
'Item 1', 150
'Item 2', 340
'Item 3', 794
'Item 4', 1205
'Item 5', 1869
'Item 2', 3412  <-- I've seen 2, So I want to inspect the item before it (5, 1869)
```

My idea is to test the distance between 2 and 5 and make a determination on if it's noise.
In this scenario, I would want to drop (Item 2, 3412) because 2 should come before 5 AND line 3412 is such a long distance away from the previous 2 (line 340), and there is also sequential items between the "last seen" item and this one.

Of course, if anyone has a better idea, I am all for that as well.

I have no idea how to walk a collection in python. I'm not even sure what type of collection I should be using. I seem to be favoring lists of paired tuples at the moment, but that's probably just me being silly.

Any guidance is appreciated.

```
for line_num, line in enumerate(all_lines):
# matching requires back-tracking - we will always be at least 1 line behind loop  
    if line_num < 1: continue  
        blob = ''.join(all_lines[line_num : line_num + _blob_length_])  
        # evaluate text aginst match expressions
        matches = self.match_patterns_sb(blob) if is_sb_edition else self.match_patterns(blob)  
        #iterate each pattern and test if match was successful
        for pattern in matches.iterkeys():
            if matches[pattern] and line_num >= last_line_matched + 1: #Try not to rematch
                if pattern == last_matched_pattern and line_num < (last_line_matched + 2) :continue  
                #store match info in a local tuple nested within a higher level list
                if not '(continued)' in blob.lower() and not '( continued )' in blob.lower():  
                    print '{0}  -  {1}'.format(pattern, line_num)
                    '''
                    At this point I want to look into last_seen, and
                    1) Get the last seen item that matches this one ('Item 2')
                    2) Get the last item added into last_seen
                    3) do some calculations 
                     '''
                    last_seen[pattern] = line_num
                    if pattern in dict(section_items).keys():
                        test = dict(section_items)
                        existing_line = test[pattern]
                        print '{0} exists with LINE NUMBER {1}'.format(pattern, existing_line)  
                    section_items.append( (pattern, line_num) )
                    # track last match
                    last_line_matched = line_num
                    last_matched_pattern = pattern
                # order and normalize the item matches
                fixed_list = OrderedDict(self.sorted_nicely(section_items, itemgetter(0))).items()
```

Comment: We're unlikely to be able to help you without seeing more context. Could you post your actual code here? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I wasn't sure if code would matter since I am so lost on how to do this. as you can see, I haven't made much progress.

Comment: Please fix your code indentation

Comment: that's also a good idea. thnx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accumulate things as you go using a `dict`, checking if you've seen it before each time.

```
sequence = [('item 1',150),('item 2',340),('item 3',794),('item 4',1205,),('item 5',1869),('item 2',3412)]
d = {}

for i,tup in enumerate(sequence):
    item,val = tup
    if d.get(item):
        print("I've seen {} before, it was {} at index {}".format(item,*d.get(item)))
    d[item] = (val, i)

#I've seen item 2 before, it was 340 at index 1
```

`d` will always have the last time you've seen `item`, or `None`.

If you need to keep track of *all* the times you've seen `item` in the past, move up to a `defaultdict` to accumulate `(item, i)` tuples into a `list` for you.

Comment: Thank you. I knew it would be something simple. I get frustrated because I know what I want to do, I just don't know how to do it in a pythonic fashion.

Comment: @Bitwise Incorrect.  I'm putting 2-tuples into the `dict`, that will not happen.

Comment: Is there a way to pull a value out by index too? What if I want to know what the last item is?

Comment: @Baywatch out of what?  The second index of `sequence` is `sequence[1]`.  Dictionaries cannot be indexed.

Comment: gotcha, but I can do something like: d.items()[-1][0] and d.items()[-1][1] to get the "last added" values. I need them to calculate the potential penalty for connecting the items.

Comment: @Baywatch I think you're misunderstanding why I used a `dict`.  The *only* thing in `d[item]` is the last time you saw `item`.  Each subsequent time you see `item`, it overwrites what is in `d[item]`.

Comment: @Baywatch and if you want to know the "thing that was most recently added to the `dict`", you can't get that without explicitly tracking it with an external variable.

Comment: @roippi Yes, I realize that. I guess this isn't really what I need though. It was a helpful lesson regardless though. I need to be able to count the "hops" between this iteration and the "last seen" item. If there are 4 items between the last time I saw Item 2 and now, then I will want to know that.

Comment: @Baywatch just compare the index of the current iteration to the one stored in the `d[item]` tuple?  That's why it's in there.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40412/discussion-between-baywatch-and-roippi)